# Failed to start redis.service: Unit redis-server.service is masked

Tags: redis, ubuntu-16.04, servicestack.redis

I Installed Redis Server on ubuntu 16.04. but when I try to start the redis service using

```
$ sudo systemctl start redis
```

I  receive message:

```
Failed to start redis.service: Unit redis-server.service is masked.
```

I don't have any idea about this error.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I found the solution. I think it will help for others
  | **systemctl unmask servicename**

```
$ sudo systemctl unmask  redis-server.service
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 20, turned out I needed to call `sudo systemctl restart redis-server` instead of `sudo systemctl restart redis`, doh!

Answer (score 21):

if **redis.service** file is missed in directory path `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` so we have to create file into this directory using command like:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/redis.service` and write following things

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store 
After=network.target

[Service]
User=redis
Group=redis
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here

- **Unit** is description and defining the network behavior,
- **Service** is to specify the service's behavior and
- **Install** define the systemd target that the service should attach to if enabled.

Then create redis user group and directories using

```
sudo adduser --system --group --no-create-home redis
```

1. `sudo mkdir /var/lib/redis` (Create directory)
2. `sudo chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis` (Change owner permission)
3. `sudo chmod 770 /var/lib/redis`

run the service `sudo systemctl start redis`
It will be work fine and check the status using

```
sudo systemctl status redis
```

Comment: I started redis-server with `redis-server /path/to/redis.conf` now, how can I check the status of my redis-server?? @aniruddh

Comment: `sudo systemctl status redis` returns `Active: active (exited)`, why is not in RUNNING mode @aniruddh

Comment: In my case i had to first remove the already existing redis user with command `sudo userdel -r redis`

Comment: This answer is missing a lot of important information if you want to install it on a centos server. I found a better explanation here: https://www.linuxcloudvps.com/blog/how-to-set-up-redis-on-centos-7/

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu users run

```
sudo systemctl restart redis-server
```

Comment: Worked great for me on Ubuntu 20, as well changing restart to status.

Answer (score 2):

You can run

> sudo systemctl restart redis-server

OR

> sudo service redis-server restart (if you are using WSL)

Answer (score 1):

1.`sudo systemctl unmask  redis-server.service`

if redis.service file is missed in directory path

`/etc/systemd/system/redis.service`  ,so we have to create file into this directory using command like:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/redis.service` **and write following things**

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store 
After=network.target

[Service]
User=redis
Group=redis
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then create redis user group and directories using

```
sudo adduser --system --group --no-create-home redis
sudo mkdir /var/lib/redis (Create directory)
sudo chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis (Change owner permission)
sudo chmod 770 /var/lib/redis
```

run the service `sudo systemctl start redis` It will be work fine and check the status using

```
sudo systemctl status redis
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed Aniruddh Rathore's answer and got errors:

```
redis.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
redis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start Redis In-Memory Data Store.
```

Then I ran

```
sudo systemctl unmask  redis-server.service
```

from other comments and it started working. Maybe that will be useful for someone.

Answer (score -1):

you must run code

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```