# Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service is masked in Ubuntu 20.04 after an upgrade from 18.4

Tags: laravel, eloquent, ubuntu-20.04

I upgraded my ubuntu from ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 20.04. On running my MySQL via the terminal, I am not able to access my DBS on running the command

```
 service MySQL start
```

I get the error message

```
Unit mysql.service is masked.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to start redis.service: Unit redis-server.service is masked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317106/failed-to-start-redis-service-unit-redis-server-service-is-masked)

Comment: In addition to being a duplicate, this is a question about server administration, not programming.

Answer (score 24):

If you are receiving the error message

> MySQL services are masked

I simply solved mine by running the below code

```
systemctl unmask mysql.service
```

Then restart your MySQL

```
service mysql start
```

Comment: Yes but, why was it masked?

Comment: Currently we can say its an upstream error while moving from any version of MySQL lower than MySQL version 8.X

Comment: I have used mysql for the better part of my coding experience and I have had a fair deal of issues with it but thanks to the support from the community I have always found work around.

Comment: I had in interesting problem, during upgrade, I was asked if I wanted to use the maintainer config version and I said yes. After the update was complete, my database server could not start. I discovered that while previously I had a my.cnf file, in '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' now it was gone and I had mysql.cnf. I copied the mysql.cnf to my.cnf and now my server is up and running

Answer (score 2):

Simply unmask mysql:

> sudo systemctl unmask mysql.service

`masked` means that it has been disabled or made inaccessible. This prevents the unit from being started or enabled.